# Ubuntu 18.04.3 USB 3 compatability

Tags: 18.04, usb, lenovo, pcie

I'm hoping someone will have some advice for me as I'm confused.

I have a SFF Lenovo M91p as a Media centre and would like to include a low profile USB 3.0 PCIe card.

Having done various searches and read numerous Q&A articles I don't seem any clearer on what works.

Many people say use NEC chipsets but others say that they don't work.

This is what I'm looking at buying....
[USB 3.0 PCIe card](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/dynamode-usb-2pci-30-lp-2x-port-usb30-pci-card-1u-low-profile-only)

I really know very little about this but understand USB 3.0 & xHCI was added to the 4+ kernels, so I'm hoping that this will work.

Any ideas??

Many thanks in advance

Comment: USB3 works on linux for many years.

Comment: Thanks for your help